# AngularJS Controller Inheritance Patterns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below controller code

```
myApp.controller('SteppersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  
    , function ($scope, $http) {



     var SteppersCtrl= (function () {
    function SteppersCtrl($mdStepper, $timeout) {
        alert('hi');
        this.$mdStepper = $mdStepper;
        this.$timeout = $timeout;
        this.isVertical = true;
        this.isLinear = false;
        this.isAlternative = true;
        this.isMobileStepText = true;
        this.campaign = false;
    }

    SteppersCtrl.prototype.selectCampaign = function () {

        var _this = this;
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.showFeedback('Checking, please wait ...');
        this.$timeout(function () {
            if (_this.campaign) {
                steppers.clearError();
                steppers.next();
            }
            else {
                _this.campaign = !_this.campaign;
                steppers.error('Wrong campaign');
            }
        }, 3000);
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.previousStep = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.back();
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.cancel = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.back();
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.nextStep = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.next();
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleMobileStepText = function () {
        this.isMobileStepText = !this.isMobileStepText;
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleLinear = function () {
        this.isLinear = !this.isLinear;
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleAlternative = function () {
        this.isAlternative = !this.isAlternative;
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleVertical = function () {
        this.isVertical = !this.isVertical;
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.showError = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.error('Wrong campaign');
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.clearError = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.clearError();
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.showFeedback = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.showFeedback('Step 1 looks great! Step 2 is comming up.');
    };
    SteppersCtrl.prototype.clearFeedback = function () {
        var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
        steppers.clearFeedback();
    };
    SteppersCtrl.$inject = [
        '$mdStepper',
        '$timeout'
    ];
    return SteppersCtrl;

}());  
  SteppersCtrl();
}]);
```

But in html file  `selectCampaign` not able to call on button click.

```
<div ui-view ng-controller="SteppersCtrl as vm" layout="column">
.................................
.................................
.................................
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="vm.selectCampaign();"/>
.................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your case controller should return an instance of `SteppersCtrl` (`return new SteppersCtrl()`). Angular creates instance of an controller using `new` but if controller constructor explicitly returns an object this object will be used as a result (this is how using constructors works in javascript - more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)). However, because `SteppersCtrl` constructor expects some dependencies to inject it will not work in this case (if you create instance of object manually with `new` keyword Angular is not aware ot this and will not inject dependencies). One of the solution is to move whole `SteppersCtrl` definition outside angular controller method and then register it as a controller. Something like this:

```
function SteppersCtrl($mdStepper, $timeout) {
    alert('hi');
    this.$mdStepper = $mdStepper;
    this.$timeout = $timeout;
    this.isVertical = true;
    this.isLinear = false;
    this.isAlternative = true;
    this.isMobileStepText = true;
    this.campaign = false;
}

SteppersCtrl.prototype.previousStep = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.back();
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.cancel = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.back();
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.nextStep = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.next();
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleMobileStepText = function () {
    this.isMobileStepText = !this.isMobileStepText;
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleLinear = function () {
    this.isLinear = !this.isLinear;
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleAlternative = function () {
    this.isAlternative = !this.isAlternative;
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.toggleVertical = function () {
    this.isVertical = !this.isVertical;
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.showError = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.error('Wrong campaign');
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.clearError = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.clearError();
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.showFeedback = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.showFeedback('Step 1 looks great! Step 2 is comming up.');
};
SteppersCtrl.prototype.clearFeedback = function () {
    var steppers = this.$mdStepper('stepper-demo');
    steppers.clearFeedback();
};

SteppersCtrl.$inject = [
    '$mdStepper',
    '$timeout'
];


myApp.controller('SteppersCtrl',  SteppersCtrl);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment i am newbie .Can you add litttle bit more code how could it should work? DO i have to change SteppersCtrl as well which is using prototype.

Comment: I've added rest ot the code - generally it's the same as in your code example. What important is that you should register your constructor function as controller - when angular creates instance of controller it will call registered function with `new` keyword and inject required dependencies

Comment: Thanks i did what you mentioned now i am getting Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SteppersCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.Only diffrent i have registered lieke this `myApp.controller('SteppersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http ) {`

Comment: Sorry that was typo its  `SteppersCtrl` only.

Comment: Any idea what can be issue.

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe you're using old Angular version which doesnt support `controller as`  syntax? here is simplified jsFiddle using angular 1.5: https://jsfiddle.net/bartekfr/yju5dstq/2/

Comment: No-2 we are using 1.5 only

Comment: Thanks its due to Typo again but i notice these all function call when i loaded the my first page of application but not call when i clicked on the button.